# PHP index array for JSON

Tags: php, json

Looking for some help.. Don't know the best approach to this issue...
I'm pushing a new reference onto an array but the "true" value is being inserted with quotes, which fails my json format.

```
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ) { 
    if($row['id']=="2"){
    $row['children']= 'true';
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data);
```

Outputs

```
[{"id":"2","name":"john","text":"john","parent_id":"0","children":"true"}]
```

When i need...

```
{"id":"2","name":"john","text":"john","parent_id":"0","children":true}]
```

How would i go about removing the qoutes or inserting it correctly first.??

Comment: for what you what that true as boolean?

Comment: JSON data is passed as a STRING so `"children":"true"` is correct! It will be usable when you get to your javascript and convert it to a javascript object

Comment: `'true'` is a string, `true` is a boolean. You want a boolean.

Comment: [Example](http://ideone.com/X7Wb7Q). Don't do `str_replace`, please.

Comment: Deleted my comment, and saw the real issue. Jakub Wrona answered it correctly.

I'm somewhat new to php, why not use str_replace if the actual solution was basically nonexistent?

Comment: @Howzieky You shouldn't use `str_replace` because it is an unreliable hack. If you put a string in the array, `json_encode` puts a string in the JSON, if you put a boolean in the array, it puts a boolean in the JSON. Instead of screwing around with the JSON string, just provide `json_encode` with values that are the correct type to begin with.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 'children' to be boolean then set it to boolean.

`while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ) { 
    if($row['id']=="2"){
    $row['children'] = true;
    }
    $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $data);`

Comment: Oh yeh! Duh!! Feel so stupid now... Thanks Jakub and others for their quick response.. Much appreciated!